# "Overwrite existing file(s)" checkbox in phpMyAdmin v4.0.6 not working

Tags: phpmyadmin

"Overwrite existing file(s)" checkbox in phpMyAdmin v4.0.6 not working
When checked or unchecked, PMA display the same message :
File [...] already exists on server, change filename or check overwrite option.

Location :
Export / Exporting databases from the current server / Output / Save output to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this bug has just been fixed for the upcoming 4.0.7 version:
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/afb393816dd2fcc8b1ddb402d644d8cbafe6e157